# LPM vs. logistic regression with complete separation of data points

Tags: logistic, nonlinear-regression

I can estimate a linear probability model on about 126,000 firm-quarter observations, but estimating the same model using logistic regression drops the usable sample to only about 75,000 observations because of complete separation of data points (certain state fixed effects have no variation in the dependent variable). Do the 51,000 observations that cannot be used in the logistic regression still add value to the estimation of my model under LPM? My question is partially motivated by the fact that the LPM produces statistically significant results, but results under logistic regression are not quite significant, and I'm wondering if it could be a power issue.